# Почему не устанавливается 1с битрикс на php 8?

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь поставить на openserver, недавно уже ставил все работало, но там php требовался от 7 версии, сейчас скачал новый установщик (php скрипт), теперь там php версия от 8, появляется эта ошибка в самом начале установки:

Повторите установку текущего шага. В случае повторения ошибки пропустите шаг.
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php on line 218 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\lib\session\handlers\abstractsessionhandler.php on line 78

В php.ini memory_limit ставил на -1 и просто увеличивал, не помогает, что делать?

Comment: `C:\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.test\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php` on line `218` жрёт очень дофига памяти посмотри что в файле не так и выпили к чёрту. Он сожрал 1,6 Гб памяти и прям писаеться как хочет ещё 262,1Кб съесть.

Comment: Я так пологаю если это тот-же файл https://bxapi.ru/src/?id=268656 то скорее всего что PHP_INT_MAX это сейчас число в девять триллионов на старых 32х битных версиях это было всего около двух миллиардов. Естественно что он не сможет выделить 9223,3 Петобайт памяти =)

Comment: Вот тут решили проблему, сам попробовал все ок http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/messages/forum6/topic153708/message732902/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, попробуйте в файле

```
\bitrix\modules\main\lib\session\handlers\abstractsessionhandler.php
```

в строке

```
$this->lastCreatedId = Random::getString(32, true);
```

вместо 32 поставить 16

```
$this->lastCreatedId = Random::getString(16, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло только полное закрытие функции getString в файле

\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php

В самой функции сразу же делаю return "...";

```
public static function getString($length, $caseSensitive = false)
{
    return "qwerty";
    
    //...
}
```

Comment: Он конечно устанавливается, но не работает авторизация в админке, поэтому нет.

Comment: Потому что возвращается строка слишком короткая.