# При установке битрикс 1с- выходит ошибка

Tags: битрикс

Выходит ошибка при установке битрикс 1 с.
Повторите установку текущего шага. В случае повторения ошибки пропустите шаг.Буду рвд любой помощи!
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted `(tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\OpenServer\domains\ventura\bitrix\modules\main\lib\security\random.php on line 103 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1525698/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-1%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-8