# Bitrix24 коробка перестал работать на openserver (php 8.1)

Tags: openserver, битрикс24, php8

ситуация такая - коробка bitrix24, работает на хостинге с bitrixvm
изначально ставилась на php7, затем обновлялась до 8 (виртуальная машина соответственно тоже)
проблема в том, что старая копия (под РНР 7, сделанная до обновления битрикса) на локалке работает, новая копия (на РНР8) - уже нет... причем при запуске никаких ошибок ни в логах ни где бы то ни было еще нет

пробовал все варианты описанные [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1525698/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-1%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-8/) - ничего не помогло

openserver, php8.1, лимит памяти выставил 10гиг, таймлимит 6000
копию разворачивал как через restore.php так и через перенос всех файлов и базы с последующими настройками подключения
так же убирал все сторонние модули и допилки которые делались - без результата
есть идеи в чем может быть проблема?